# how to add values using mongodb aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

is there any way to add values via aggregation
like db.insert_one

```
x = db.aggregate([{
    "$addFields": {
        "chat_id": -10013345566,
    }
}])
```

i tried this
but this code return nothing and values are not updated

i wanna add the values via aggregation
cuz aggregation is way faster than others

sample document :

```
    {"_id": 123 , "chat_id" : 125}
    {"_id": 234, "chat_id" : 1325}
    {"_id": 1323 , "chat_id" : 335}
```

expected output :

alternative to db.insert_one() in mongodb aggregation

Comment: Share a sample document and expected output

Comment: @hhharsha36 check edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of `$merge` stage to save output of the aggregation to the collection.

> **Note:** Be very very careful when you use `$merge` stage as you can accidentally replace the entire document in your collection. Go through the complete documentation of this stage before using it.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 123
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "chat_id": -10013345566,
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",  // <- Collection Name
      "on": "_id",  // <- Merge operation match key
      "whenMatched": "merge"  // <- Operation to perform when matched
    }
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ku0Pg-KIN0j)

Comment: but i want to update only single value tho

Comment: In that case you have to make sure that only that single field and `_id` field are returned before the last stage and perform `$merge` with `whenMatched: "merge"` option. Regardless, what you are looking for can be achieved only by `$merge` stage.